# Threejs and orbitcontrol

Tags: javascript, three.js

I don't understand if it is a pure javascript mistake or not. In the class function below I added an eventListener that return me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

I want to clarify that all the function called are correctly defined.

```
function OrbitController(v){
var that = this;
this.view = v;
this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.view.getCamera(),this.view.renderer.domElement);
this.controls.addEventListener( 'change', that.view.show());// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this solution:

```
this.controls.addEventListener( 'change',  function(){ that.view.show()});
```

Comment: You should avoid this pattern because you can't remove the change listener later.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `that.view.show()` **returns** a function, then it should just be

```
this.controls.addEventListener( 'change', that.view.show );
```