# Add OrbitalControl to Three.js results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add OrbitalControls to a Three.js Script. 
The Code should just add two spheres to an empty space and let the user look around the spheres with the OrbitalControls, but whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

```
three.js:5353 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined
    at Sphere.copy (three.js:5353)
    at Frustum.intersectsObject (three.js:5792)
    at projectObject (three.js:22427)
    at projectObject (three.js:22472)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:22230)
    at animate (index.html:50)
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scope = this;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
camera.position.z = 5;
scope.controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(){scope.render} );
controls.update();

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var v = new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1);
var v0 = new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2);

var sphere = new THREE.Sphere(v, .1);
var sphere0 = new THREE.Sphere(v0, .1);
var m = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, material);
var m0 = new THREE.Mesh(sphere0, material);
scene.add(m);
scene.add(m0);

animate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    scope.controls.update();
    scope.renderer.render( scope.scene, scope.camera );
}
```

I have already looked at the following resources but couldn't figure out how to solve the problem:

- [Threejs and orbitcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240089/threejs-and-orbitcontrol)
- [Three.js + OrbitControls - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204203/three-js-orbitcontrols-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-render-of)
- [three.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039553/three-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-center-of-undefined/35856775) (with that one I am not sure if it is related to the problem.)
- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/controls/OrbitControls

Can you please tell me where my error is and how a possible solution could look like?

Comment: `THREE.Sphere()` and `THREE.SphereGeometry()`/`THREE.SphereBufferGeometry()` are different things, intended for different purposes. Now, what you're trying to do is to pass a `THREE.Sphere()` object to the constructor of `THREE.Mesh()`, when you have to pass a (buffered) geometry, like `THREE.SphereGeometry()` or `THREE.SphereBufferGeometry()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Sphere` represents a bounding sphere whereas `THREE.SphereGeometry` or `THREE.SphereBufferGeometry` represents geometries. Since you create a mesh always with a geometry and not with a bounding volume, just switch to `THREE.SphereBufferGeometry` to solve the problem.